# Questionnaire, Referral E-mail add

Tags: php, email, email-client

We need to send a questionnaire to our clients. I've done that, and it is working.

**What it does:**

- I send the link via e-mail
- my clients open the link from e-mail
- they fill it in; and finally
- the little script sends their response back to me.

The problem I have is that I want to know which client have responded to my questionnaire? I tried all of the `$_SERVER` vars, but I can't find the e-mail address.

I'm afraid if I ask the user for their e-mail address in the questionnaire, they may give me a fake address.

How can I get their e-mail address reliably?

Comment: You can pass some argument via $_GET (like: http://mywebsite.com/mail?somebody=john) with your link and when you client click on that link, you page can treat that param easily

Comment: Yes ! @GuilhermeFerreira is exactly right. You should use this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and the text corrections too. - The @GuilhermeFerreira solution is perfect, but I have more than hundred clients.

Comment: Did you already sent these mails and now you want know who clicked or do you will send soon ?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira - No, I want to make it correctly and then send mails.

Comment: You have a second option creating a relationship between your client (ie. email) and one internal number and, send that number using $_GET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use unique identifier for each link that you send by email.

For instance, you could make database table in which would be each of the mails assigned to an id. Like this.

```
+-----+-------------------+
|  ID |  Mail             |
+-----+-------------------+
|  1  | Random@mail.com   |
|  2  | another@gmail.com |
+-------------------------+
```

Now you could fetch all the mails from database, loop through the array of them and generate link for each of them, in which would be in GET reference to an ID in database (so you would not have to use the real email address in the link).

Link would look like `myaddress.com/form.php?id=1` and the ID corresponding to the given mail would be in `$_GET["id"]`.

---

*Note #1* that you should definitively check the `$_GET["id"]` for possible SQL injection before using it for identifying the mail.

*Note #2* that it is from user perspective better to use id in the address instead of the full user mail, hence it doesn't raise as much attention as a number and id, so the user will not try to gamble with that.